# Escape to IntelliJ IDEA shortcuts from IdeaVim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm used to both vim and IntelliJ default hotkeys. I'd like to not to have to change any of them - I'd rather like to be able to use conflicting IntelliJ bindings, like CTRL-P for example, after some kind of escape key.

Conflict balloon and my [research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ideavim%20escape%20hotkeys) wasn't too helpful. Only thing that I've found is that I can turn vim plugin off with a hotkey, and then back on after I'm done, but I have to remember to turn it one every time.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just turn VIM plugin off, execute keystroke, then turn it back on.  I have <kbd>^Z</kbd> bound to the VIM Emulator command for this purpose and it's enough for me.  To set this up, go to Preferences... => Keymap, search for "vim emulator", and right-click on the command name to assign a shortcut.

But if you have a limited set of IntelliJ commands you want to use with a prefix key, you could pick the prefix key, make sure it is unbound in IntelliJ, and then use it in your `~/.ideavimrc` along with the original binding you wan to invoke.

For example, <kbd>^D</kbd> in VIM is "Scroll window Downwards" and in IntelliJ (with keymap "Mac OS X 10.5+") is "Debug".  If you want to be able to use both:

- choose a prefix key that's not bound in IntelliJ, say <kbd>^Z</kbd>
- in Other Settings => Vim Emulation, find shortcut <kbd>^D</kbd> and set the handler to Vim.
- In your `~/.ideavimrc`, add the following mapping:

  `nnoremap <C-Z><C-D> :action Debug<CR>`

Now you can type <kbd>^D</kbd> for the Vim action scroll down, or <kbd>^Z</kbd><kbd>^D</kbd> for the IntelliJ action Debug, without actually disabling IdeaVIM.  You'll of course have to add a mapping to your ~/.ideavimrc for each IntelliJ command you want to execute this way, but if you have a limited number you can set them up once and be done with it.

Comment: That's a start of an interesting idea. I guess it's possible to parse IntelliJ and IdeaVim keymap files, and then make `.ideavimrc` that contains bindings for all conflicted mappings. I could do that and fit in in your answer and then accept it; I've just yet to find respective files (I've only found custom IDEA keymap .xml file and no default so far).

Comment: How did you configure vimemulator with ^Z? I'm not able to do it.

Comment: @Onewildgamer I second this. "I just turn VIM plugin off, execute keystroke, then turn it back on. I have ^Z bound to the VIM Emulator command for this purpose and it's enough for me." -- how do you do this?

Comment: @Ryan, I just edited the answer to add instructions.

Comment: To find all actions, type `:actionlist`.
Here is what i did to bind _VCS/Commit_ action: 1) In _IdeaVim / Settings_ set _Ctrl+K_ _"Commit..."_ to _IDE_ handler; 2) list all actions with `:actionlist` command; 3) found _C-K_ there and copied action name - _CheckinProject_; 4) In _IdeaVim / Settings_ set _Ctrl+K "Commit..."_ to _Vim_ handler; 5) add map in `~/.ideavimrc` - `nnoremap <C-z><C-k>:action CheckinProject<CR>`; 6) `:source ~/.ideavimrc`.

Answer (score 71):

I made [.ideavimrc](https://github.com/melihovv/cfgs/blob/master/roles/vim/files/.ideavimrc) that contains bindings for all conflicted mappings. Maybe it'll be usefull to someone.

```
imap jj <Esc>

let mapleader = " "
map <leader>a :action $SelectAll<CR>
map <leader>b :action GotoDeclaration<CR>
map <leader>c :action $Copy<CR>
map <leader>d :action EditorDuplicate<CR>
map <leader>e :action RecentFiles<CR>
map <leader>f :action Find<CR>
map <leader>g :action GotoLine<CR>
map <leader>h :action TypeHierarchy<CR>
map <leader>i :action ImplementMethods<CR>
map <leader>m :action EditorScrollToCenter<CR>
map <leader>n :action FileChooser.NewFolder<CR>
map <leader>o :action OverrideMethods<CR>
map <leader>p :action ParameterInfo<CR>
map <leader>q :action QuickJavaDoc<CR>
map <leader>r :action Replace<CR>
map <leader>s :action SaveAll<CR>
map <leader>t :action Vcs.UpdateProject<CR>
map <leader>u :action GotoSuperMethod<CR>
map <leader>v :action $Paste<CR>
map <leader>w :action EditorSelectWord<CR>
map <leader>x :action $Cut<CR>
map <leader>y :action EditorDeleteLine<CR>
map <leader>[ :action EditorCodeBlockStart<CR>
map <leader>] :action EditorCodeBlockEnd<CR>
```

Comment: Cool <3        Cool <3        Cool <3

Comment: Saved my day - now I have a bunch of stuff to add there :)

Comment: I have try it, but MethodHierarchy.OverrideMethodAction not work.

Comment: I updated answer. You can use :actionlist command to see all intellij actions to customize these mappings.

Comment: On my system (Win7 x64, PyCharm 2017.1.3) I needed to replace `map` with `nnoremap` in order to get this work. Great idea though, thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason, I don't manage to get `<leader>r` open the replace window in visual mode, even if using `noremap` or `vnoremap` in this mapping.

Comment: Can you do <leader>pf ?

Comment: what is "leader"?

Comment: @Ted leader key is whatever you define, if you read carefully there's is line saying `let mapleader = " "` which make <space> a leader key, for example  `<space>+b ` translates  to `:goto declaration`

Comment: To have IdeaVim read your changes to .ideavimrc, use `:source ~/.ideavimrc`

Answer (score 5):

Adding onto the excellent answer by @melihovv, I have added the Run, Debug, and Choose Configuration actions to my `~/.ideavimrc`.

```
map <leader>dd :action Debug<CR>
map <leader>cd :action ChooseDebugConfiguration<CR>
map <leader>rr :action Run<CR>
map <leader>cr :action ChooseRunConfiguration<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

A [keymap](https://anotepad.com/notes/7g8gn4) without any bindings here: to be used, so one could start from clean slate configuring the *.ideavimrc*

Answer (score 0):

A simple option may also be to use insert mode for IntelliJ Keybindings. I'm just starting out with ideavim and this seems to do it for me, for now..